# Display image from URL in swift, unwrapping error

Tags: url, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to display image to imageView from URL. I successfully done it using synchronous method in a simple project. But this application is used for online store, so I took product information and image URL from a JSON file. which I'm sure I was successfully stored all the data in a product array. But the problem I'm facing is this:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the code.

```
// UnWrapping imageURL
        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: actualCurrentProduct.imageURL)

        if let actualURL = url {

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: actualURL)

            if let actualImageData = imageData {

               self.productImageView.image = UIImage(data: actualImageData)
            }
        }
```

It highlighted in this particular code.

> self.productImageView.image = UIImage(data: actualImageData)

Anybody have any idea why? Really appreciated it.

Comment: working fine for me..check ur URL may be that is causing this problem.

Comment: Maybe `self.productImageView` is `nil`?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I have check the url and it works.

Comment: @rintaro It should not be nil. I have checked it using break points each line.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display the image successfully from URL with this code. I started the project from the scratch and for the display image part, here is my code.

```
let imageURL = NSURL(string: actualCurrentProduct.imageURL)
        if let actualImageURL = imageURL {

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: actualImageURL)
            if let actualImageData = imageData {

                let image = UIImage(data: actualImageData)
                if let actualImage = image {

                    self.productImage.image = actualImage

                }
            }
        }
```

Finally....